# registering custom protocol at installation process in electron app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Hi I am new to electron and was wondering how i can register a custom protocol for the app at the time of installation process of the app.

I am using electron-builder for building the app. Here is the build build code

```
"build": {
"appId": "com.test.testapp",
"productName": "testapp",
"asar": true,
"protocols": [{
  "name": "testapp",
  "schemes": [ "testapp" ]
}],
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true,
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "runAfterFinish": false,
  "createDesktopShortcut": true
},
"squirrelWindows": {
  "msi": true
},
"directories": {
  "output": "distribution"
}
```

I know that by adding the below line registers the custom protocol

```
 app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("testapp");
```

but it only does if i run the app at least the first time.

Which i don't want there is no guarantee that the user will launch the app after installation.

So is there a way that i can register the custom protocol in the installation process using electron-builder

Answer (score 9):

I'm still new to Electron and electron-builder but solved this problem for NSIS-target already. First of all I should note that `app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient` used to handle custom protocols inside the application as far as I do understand. You need to register this custom protocol using electron-builder itself.

Secondly I need to choose between NSIS and squirrelWindows. NSIS is the preferable as long I understand because Squirrel is less supported and has some problems. Again I'm not an expert but I read something about it. So squirrelWindows section is redundant. You don't specify `win.target` and it is `"nsis"` by default.

There is a problem with the custom protocol registration for NSIS target. You can read more here: [Protocol (scheme) for windows](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/623) but there is a workaround. You need to create a file named `installer.nsh` in your `build` folder with such a content:

```
!macro customInstall
  DetailPrint "Register evehq-ng URI Handler"
  DeleteRegKey HKCR "evehq-ng"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng" "" "URL:evehq-ng"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng" "EveHQ NG SSO authentication Protocol" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng\shell" "" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng\shell\Open" "" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "evehq-ng\shell\Open\command" "" "$INSTDIR\${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME} %1"
!macroend
```

Replace `evehq-ng` with your protocol string and `EveHQ NG SSO authentication Protocol` with your protocol description.

After that you have to set `nsis.perMachine` to true.

I haven't yet solved this problem for Linux but work in this direction. You can see my code in my proof of concepts project here: [EveHQ-NG proof of concepts application](https://github.com/Eshva/EveHQ-NG.Prototype).

If you will solve this problem for Linux and MacOS write me a message somehow here or on GitHub.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works, but `EveHQ NG SSO authentication Protocol` should be changed to `URL Protocol`. It's not a configurable string for description, but a fixed one.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `electron-builder` you can do the following:

```
"build": {
    ... other top level electron-builder keys ...
    "protocols": [
       {
           "name": "Custom Protocol Name",
           "schemes": [
               "customProtocol"
           ]
       }
    ]
}
```

In case you wanted to handle `customProtocol://some-link` with your application.

More details:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

(Search for `protocols`; as of now, the documentaion is a little mis-formatted. It's supposed to be the same top-level key as the `fileAssociations` key above it.)

Answer (score 1):

custom protocol is still opening only after opening the electron application. And I also added **installer.nsh** inside build folder. I don't know what's the problem.

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "electron-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick" : false , 
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true, 
      "include" : "dist/installer.nsh" , 
      "perMachine" : true 
    },
    "protocols": [{
      "name": "electron-deep-linking",
      "schemes": [
        "test"
      ]
    }],
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.Reference"
    }
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {

    mainWindow = null
  })
}
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('test')

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Electron providing a very simple way to registering custom protocol URL in client machine(Windows, Mac)

so this way we can register and remove our own custom protocol in machine

```
const {app} = require('electron')
app.on('ready', onReady)

function onReady() {

    .... // write other code 
    if(!app.isDefaultProtocolClient('quickstart')) {
        app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("quickstart", 'C:\\Users\\karthi\\electron-quick-start\\electron-quick-start-win32-x64\\electron-quick-start.exe');

    }
}
```

this code will register the custom protocol in machine, then you can open your app using browser like `quickstart://params`

for removing the custom protocol in machine

```
app.removeAsDefaultProtocolClient("quickstart", 'C:\\Users\\karthi\\electron-quick-start\\electron-quick-start-win32-x64\\electron-quick-start.exe');
```

here i used electron quick start app and i used `electron-packager` npm for building my app

For more information custom protocol [electron-protocol](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args)

Comment: The question is about registration at installation time which stated clearly in the question so this answer does not apply.

Comment: +1  I found this question because I was accustomed to dealing with registry stuff in the installer.  This solution works better for my needs.  Makes switching the protocol from dev to staging a breeze too.